# Use of「など」and ~にまで

Tags: grammar, particle-に, reading-comprehension, particle-まで, particle-など

I've been watching some kind a medieval fantasy *anime* and I stumbled upon the following sentence :

**Context :** A character explain how his clan rose to power.

> ついには、年貢{ねんぐ}取{と}り立{た}てに検査{けんさ}制度{せいど}を導入{どうにゅう}するなどまつりごとにまで影響力{えいきょうりょく}を持つようになった我{わ}が一族{いちぞく}。

There are two things, I don't really understand in this sentence :

1. How does ~にまで work in this sentence ? What does **まつりごとにまで** mean ?
2. I think「など」is used to give an example of something but I'm not sure I really understand what (maybe  because of 1.) ?

Basically, I don't really understand those "structures" and their potential nuances of meaning in this context.

I tried to roughly translate what I understand of the sentence and I got :

*Finally, my clan went as far as bringing in things like a system of inspection, as an annual tribute, in order to gain influence.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you almost got it.

1. にまで: に comes from **Xに**影響力を持つ = have influence **over X**. まで here is [極端な例をあげて、他の場合を言外に推測させる意を表す。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7/#jn-208999), or more practically *even* (it is possible to use *as far as*, like you tried).
2. You are correct in that など indicates an example. 年貢取り立てに検査制度を導入する is an example of まつりごと (or まつりごとへの影響力), which is an archaic word for *politics* (rendered 政 in Kanji). So the sentence gives introduction of inspection into annual tributes as an example of politics.

So the whole sentence means, *Our clan that came to have influence even over politics, e.g. bringing in inspection system in requisition of annual tributes.*